# Bluebird Promisify execFile can't get promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Please excuse my noobness, but why isn't this working?
`then()` is never fired, and neither is `error()`. Promise seems to never resolve.

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
execFile = Promise.promisify(execFile);
var IMAGE_DIR = "resources/assets/images";
var validImages = ['.jpg', '.png'];

 ... // setup omitted ... 

execFile('find', [IMAGE_DIR], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  var images = [];
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var fileList = stdout.split('\n');
    images = fileList.filter(function (image) {
      var ext = path.extname(image);
      if (validImages.indexOf(ext) > -1) {
        return image;
      }
    })
    return resolve(images);
  })
}).then(function () {
  console.log(arguments);
}).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: You must not pass a callback to promisfied functions. And you should never call the `new Promise` constructor yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just not using the promisified version of `execFile()` properly.

You should be doing:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const execFile = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);

execFile('find', [IMAGE_DIR]).then(function(stdout) {
    // process result here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

---

If you need access to both `stdout` and `stderr`, then you have to pass the multiArgs option to `.promisify()`.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const execFile = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').execFile, {multiArgs: true});

execFile('find', [IMAGE_DIR]).then(function(args) {
    let stdout = args[0];
    let stderr = args[1];
    // process result here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I highly appreciate the answer given by [jfriend000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00). Anyways, if you want a ES7 solution with async-await:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const execFile = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').execFile

const find = async () => {
  try{
      let output = await execFile('find', [IMAGE_DIR]);
      // handle your output with the variable
  } catch(error) {
      // handle your errors here
  }
}
```